# Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS Shim - getHistoryForKey

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm working with the NodeJS `fabric-shim` library and I'm wondering if the

[getHistoryForKey](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getHistoryForKey__anchor)

API returns the history of key values across time ordered chronologically ( starting from the oldest value to the latest one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it returns chronologically all the transactions related to the key value that are stored in the world state of the network.